# Forma "limpa" de fazer a modificação do atributo "visible" de uma PictureBox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Tenho 5 imagens de fundo para minha aplicação e que ficara visível ao gosto do usuário. Qual a maneira mais simples (código limpo) de fazer que o usuário escolha?

```
    private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox1.Visible = true;
        pictureBox2.Visible = false;
        pictureBox3.Visible = false;
        pictureBox4.Visible = false;
        pictureBox5.Visible = false;
    }
    private void radioButton2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox2.Visible = true;
        pictureBox1.Visible = false;
        pictureBox3.Visible = false;
        pictureBox4.Visible = false;
        pictureBox5.Visible = false;
    }
    private void radioButton3_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox1.Visible = false;
        pictureBox2.Visible = false;
        pictureBox3.Visible = true;
        pictureBox4.Visible = false;
        pictureBox5.Visible = false;
    }
    private void radioButton4_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox1.Visible = false;
        pictureBox2.Visible = false;
        pictureBox3.Visible = false;
        pictureBox4.Visible = true;
        pictureBox5.Visible = false;
    }
    private void img5_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox1.Visible = false;
        pictureBox2.Visible = false;
        pictureBox3.Visible = false;
        pictureBox4.Visible = false;
        pictureBox5.Visible = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assim:

```
private void radioButtonUnico_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pictureBox1.Visible = false;
    pictureBox2.Visible = false;
    pictureBox3.Visible = false;
    pictureBox4.Visible = false;
    pictureBox5.Visible = false;

    switch (((RadioButton)sender).Name) {
        case "radioButton1": 
            pictureBox1.Visible = true;
            break;
        case "radioButton2": 
            pictureBox2.Visible = true;
            break;
        case "radioButton3": 
            pictureBox3.Visible = true;
            break;
        case "radioButton4": 
            pictureBox4.Visible = true;
            break;
        case "radioButton5": 
            pictureBox5.Visible = true;
            break;
    }
}
```

Defina o evento para todos os seus `RadioButtons`.

Answer (score 8):

A Resposta do Cigano Morrison Mendez é boa e resolve o problema. Mas alguém pode ter um problema onde não consegue mudar a estrutura dos métodos. Ainda assim tem uma solução:

```
private void ChangePictureBoxes() {
    pictureBox1.Visible = false;
    pictureBox2.Visible = false;
    pictureBox3.Visible = false;
    pictureBox4.Visible = false;
    pictureBox5.Visible = false;
}

private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    ChangePictureBoxes();
    pictureBox1.Visible = true;
}
private void radioButton2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    ChangePictureBoxes()
    pictureBox2.Visible = true;
}
private void radioButton3_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    ChangePictureBoxes()
    pictureBox3.Visible = true;
}
private void radioButton4_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    ChangePictureBoxes()
    pictureBox4.Visible = true;
}
private void img5_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    ChangePictureBoxes()
    pictureBox5.Visible = true;
}
```

Eventualmente é possível usar o método utilitário da maneira como o Sunstreaker sugeriu, desde que você saiba que todos os `PictureBox` devem receber aquele estado. De fato se a semântica mais adequada é "todos `PictureBox`es" ao invés de "os `PictureBox`es tal e tal", esta seria uma solução mais genérica e duradoura, apesar de possivelmente ter uma perda de performance mas provavelmente irrelevante.

```
private void ChangePictureBoxes() {
    foreach (var p in Controls.OfType<PictureBox>()) p.Visible = false;
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/WinForms/EnableProperty.cs).

Não sou fã do termo atributo neste contexto, prefiro campo e demonstro porque em [Qual a diferença entre atributo e campo, nas classes?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/269089/101).

Answer (score 7):

Você pode pegar **todos**(*se isso não for problema para você*) os componentes do tipo [`PictureBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox.aspx) e colocá-los em uma [coleção](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ybcx56wz.aspx), e num *loop* mudar a propriedade *Visible* para `false`, e depois no `PictureBox` **alvo** mudar para `true` a propriedade *Visible*.
Algo assim:

```
   var pictureBoxes = Controls.OfType<PictureBox>();
   foreach (var p in pictureBoxes) p.Visible = false;
   pictureBox1.Visible = true;
```

Faça isso no evento `CheckedChanged()` de todos os seus `RadioButton's` apenas alterando o nome do `pictureBox` alvo.

Comment: Tem só um problema: e se houverem mais do que cinco `PictureBox` no `Form` dele, e as outras não forem modificadas?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez Acho que isso não vai ser problema, **pelo menos não para o OP**, segundo ele, existem apenas 5 `picturebox`.

Comment: Aceita sugestão? Que tal minimizar sua resposta pra um evento só?

Comment: Agora sim. Excelente. +1.

Answer (score 0):

Considerando que está sendo utilizado o controle `RadioButton` junto ao evento `CheckedChanged`, poderíamos dizer que há um problema até de lógica com seu código.

Caso alguma outra parte do seu sistema altere o estado da propriedade `checked` para `false` e seu controle estivesse checado, o evento `CheckedChanged` seria disparado, resultando em algo não desejado...
É importante lembrar que os eventos não são disparados apenas por ações dos usuários via `UI`.

Deixo como sugestão o código abaixo.

Crie um método que controle a visibilidade dos `PictureBoxes` baseada na propriedade `checked` de cada `RadioButon` relacionado à eles.

```
private void ChangePictureBoxes()
{
    pictureBox1.Visible = radioButton1.Checked;
    pictureBox2.Visible = radioButton2.Checked;
    pictureBox3.Visible = radioButton3.Checked;
    pictureBox4.Visible = radioButton4.Checked;
    pictureBox5.Visible = radioButton5.Checked;    
}
```

Faça a chamada deste método em cada evento dos seus `RadioButton`:

```
private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ChangePictureBoxes();
}
```