# Pegar informações do objeto sender

Tags: c#, .net, objetos

Como funciona a busca de informações atraves do objeto sender e em quais situações posso usa-lo, com quais tipos de eventos?
Isso para evitar redundância de eventos.  Onde posso explorar essas possibilidades?
Por exemplo :
vários botões de 0 a 9. E gerar um evento único para todo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O `sender` é do tipo `Object`, e tem a funcionalidade de quando o evento for executado, receber as informações de tal controle, por exemplo, se você clicar em um `Button` ele traz as informações desse Button.

*Exemplo:*

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Em um formulário possui dois `Button`, um tem no seu `Text` com *Mensagem 1* e *Mensagem 2* respecitvamente o `ButMensagem1` foi colocado na sua propriedade `Tag` o número ***1*** e no `ButMensagem2` foi colocado o número ***2***. Como recuperar essas informações:

*Código:*

***Obs:*** Lembrando que o evento `Click` vai ser o mesmo para os dois `Button`

```cs
private void ButMensagem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Button butMensagem = (Button)sender;
    //ou 
    Button butMensagem = sender as Button; 
    switch (((string)butMensagem.Tag))
    {
        case "1": // mensagem 1
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Botão Clicado: Mensagem 1", "Clicado", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                break;
            }
        case "2": // mensagem 2
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Botão Clicado: Mensagem 2", "Clicado", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                break;
            }
    }

}
```

Ou seja, usando um [Cast](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms173105.aspx) você recupera qual `Button` foi clicado e com isso recupera as  configurações, eventos e propriedades. No caso foi recuperado a propriedade `Tag` e com isso a rotina toma a decisão de mostrar a *Mensagem 1* ou *Mensagem 2*, dependendo do Button que foi acionado.

Answer (score 3):

O `sender` deve ser entendido como um objeto coringa: a ideia de ele não ser tipado é justamente para que ele possa ser manipulado por eventos em que os tipos do objeto sejam diferentes, e que um único evento possa estar ligado a vários objetos.

[Nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/17469/forma-limpa-de-fazer-a-modificacao-do-atributo-visible-de-uma-picturebox/17474#17474), digo como se pode escrever um único evento que manipule várias `PictureBoxes`. Repare que a solução sugere converter o `sender` para um tipo para realizar a manipulação de alguma propriedade ou implementar alguma regra de negócio (para o caso da pergunta, manipular a visibilidade quando o objeto é assinalado).

Seu exemplo já responde bem uma das vantagens de usar o `sender`, como trabalhar os valores de vários botões. O limite das possibilidades está justamente na quantidade de propriedades que o objeto possui. Após o *casting*, você pode ler e manipular a propriedade que desejar (deste que a propriedade não seja somente-leitura).