# Capturar TextBox que chamou o evento

Tags: c#, winforms

Estou querendo implementar o vento [`GotFocus`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.control.gotfocus(v=vs.110).aspx) em um `TextBox`, para que quando, ele receba o foco, ele defina a propriedade `Text` como  `string.empty`.

Porém, eu tenho 6 `TextBox` que irão executar esse evento. Como identifico qual o `TextBox`? E como defino a propriedade `Text`como `string.empty`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usando o `sender` que é recebido por parâmetro no evento.

```
private void txtBox_GotFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var txt = (TextBox)sender;
    txt.Text = "";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Nesta [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/17780/46243) foi dada uma boa explicação sobre o `sender`.

Para o seu caso, completando a resposta do jbueno, implementei uma forma de você atribuir a todos os textbox o evento `GotFocus`.
Inclusive, uma forma de atribuir somente a um determinado grupo de controles.

*O `region` que criei pode ser convertido em um método se quiser.*

```
public Form1() {
    InitializeComponent();

    #region Atribui a TODOS os textbox o evento GetFocus            
    //cria uma lista com todos os controles do formulário do tipo TextBox
    var listTextBox = this.Controls?.OfType<TextBox>();

    //Se por exemplo, você tiver um conjunto de textbox onde, só a eles deseja esse evento,
    //então poderá filtrar pelo nome deles - ou qualquer outra propriedade    
    var listTextBox = this.Controls?.OfType<TextBox>().Where(p => p.Name.Contains("TextBoxOpcoes"));

    foreach (var item in listTextBox) {
        item.Enter += new EventHandler(TextBoxOpcoes_GotFocus);
    }            
    #endregion
}

//Método que irá limpar a propriedade Text do controle
private void TextBoxOpcoes_GotFocus(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    ((TextBox)sender).Text = String.Empty;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Uma maneira mais elegante seria!

```
    private void DataGridViewRegistrosCell_TextChanged_Exemplo(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            var cellValue = (sender as TextBox).Text;
            Debug.WriteLine($"O valor da célula é: {cellValue}");
    }
```