# Percorrer componentes do form C#

Tags: c#, foreach, loop

Olá tenho um tabela vinda do banco de dados, com varias linha e colunas. Uma desta colunas está armazenado o endereço da imagem salva anteriormente. Agora preciso percorrer o todos os PictureBox e colocar no ImageLocation o endereço dessas imagem. Ah, sim! Antes que eu me esqueça tenho 10  PictureBox  no form.
Estou usando seguinte código:

```
foreach (Control item in this.Controls)  
{  
if (item is PictureBox)
{
item.Name.ToString();//Até aqui tudo certo, consigo ver nome dele, mas preciso pegar nome e a propriedade ImageLocation 
}
```

Alguém tem uma ideia?

Comment: Quer dizer que você tem uma lista de endereços de imagens no DB e você quer carregar essas imagens nos respectivos picture-boxes?

Comment: Em que variável estão carregadas as informações do banco de dados. Você está usando algum ORM: EntityFramework, NHibernate?

Comment: @MiguelAngelo um variável do tipo  DataTable, e estou percorrendo as linhas e colunas usando um for

Comment: @MiguelAngelo Estou usando windows form C#.

Comment: Mas ai pra cada Row percorrida do DataTable, você quer carregar a imagem no próximo PictureBox disponível... seria isso?

Comment: @MiguelAngelo Isso mesmo. + ou - assim: PictureBox1.ImageLocation = Tabela.Rows[0][0].ToString(); PictureBox2.ImageLocation = Tabela.Rows[1][0].ToString();

Comment: @FabrícioSimoneAlanaMendes Veja se alguma das respostas [dessa pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/17469/6454) ajudam você.

Comment: @Qmechanic73 meu código já está assim, eu gostaria mesmo de fazer isso didinâmico.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vou te sugerir o seguinte:

1. criar os PictureBox de forma dinâmica, ao invés de adicioná-los um a um pelo designer:

   ```
   public partial class Form1 : Form
   {
       private PictureBox[] pictures;

       public Form1()
       {
           InitializeComponent();

           // criando as 10 PictureBox de que necessita
           this.pictures = Enumerable.Range(1, 10)
               .Select(this.CriarPictureBox)
               .ToArray();

           // eu estou adicionando dentro de um FlowLayout, mas poderia ser no Form,
           // ou dentro de qualquer outro contêiner de sua escolha
           this.flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.AddRange(this.pictures);
       }

       private PictureBox CriarPictureBox(int i)
       {
           return new PictureBox
           {
               Name = "pic" + i,
               Location = new Point(0, 0),
               Size = new Size(100, 100),
               BackColor = Color.Black,
               Visible = true,
           };
       }
   }
   ```
2. com os PictureBox em um array, agora você pode se referir a eles usando um índice numérico, dentro do laço de carregamento que lê o DataTable. Exemplo:

   ```
   private void CarregarImagens(DataTable tabela, int primeiraRow)
   {
       for (int itPic = 0; itPic < this.pictures.Length; itPic++)
       {
           this.pictures[itPic].ImageLocation =
               tabela.Rows[itPic + primeiraRow]["NomeColuna"].ToString();
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Chegou até aqui sem resposta. veja como resolvi meu problema

```
//Primeiro percorri as colunas do datatable;
for (int i = 0; i < Tabela.Rows.Count; i++)
{
//Garanti que as células não estejam vazias
Celula = Tabela.Rows[i][0].ToString();
if (Celula != "")
{
//Usei um switch para analisar a variável i do for
switch (i)
{
case 0:
PictureBox1.ImageLocation = Tabela.Rows[i][0].ToString();
break;
case 1:
ptb2lugar.ImageLocation = Tabela.Rows[i]0].ToString();
break;
case2:
ptb3lugar.ImageLocation = Tabela.Rows[i][0].ToString();
break;
case 3:
PictureBox2.ImageLocation = Tabela.Rows[i][0].ToString();
break;
}
}
}
```